Scanning nfc tag from passport and using data from it in android emulator, to emulate passport scanning using nfc
Hi, I am running tests of nfc scan emulation in android emulator.
I have encountered a number of problems while performing this task

How to scan data from nfc tag on a posport ? (And in what format to save them, encrypted or not).
How to emulate scanning ? (I suspect that it is enough to save encrypted data from posport and transmit it during emulation).

In the end I would like to achieve the following, I scan passport data with my phone -> save it and use it during emulation (it would be great if I could use proxy for applications in the emulator)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
